# Compile error when trying to compile a qt project

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, makefile

I am trying to compile my Qt project that compiles fine on a Linux machine, however on my Mac
I get the following error:

```
    ../../Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/clang_64/include/QtCore/qlist.h:52:10: fatal error: 
  'initializer_list' file not found
   #include <initializer_list>
     ^
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a known bug for mac when trying to compile a Qt 5.0+ project with a 64 bit clang compiler. In order to resolve this conflict try the steps outlined in [this](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-28097) bug fix forum post:

1) Clone the Desktop Qt 5.0.0 clang 64bit (SDK) kit.

2) Change the compiler from GCC (x86 64bit) to Clang (x86 64bit).

3) Change your project to use the cloned kit.

4) Add the following to your .pro file:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS = -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -std=gnu0x -stdlib=libc+

CONFIG +=c++11
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit further how i can accomplish steps 1, 2, 3, or at least direct me to the right resources?

Comment: 1. Copypasta your Qt SDK root directory somewhere else. 2/3. Navigate in QtCreator to Projects-> Manage Kits -> Kits and select the kit you are currently using or create a new kit. With a kit selected, specify the path to the Qt SDK clone under Sysroot and an Clang x86 64 bit compiler under Compiler.

Comment: I am still not clear on this, I don't see any Qt SDK folder, does this mean to copy and paste the whole Qt.5.0.1 floder somewhere else? the current SDK has the same attribute, like the compiler is Clang x86 64 bit. Sorry for dragging this, but I have to make this running

Comment: Yes, that is the directory the post was referring to. I assume they want you to clone that directory just in case the Qt installation your using gets mangled and you have a working back up.

Comment: do you know if the Clang x86 64 bit supports C++11?

Comment: Cloning the kit seems to be unnecessary now; the compiler is already Clang. However, I still needed to make (some of) the prescribed changes to my .pro file.

Comment: FWIW, I had success just adding the line `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS = -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++`